# concatenation of multiple std::array objects using variadic templates

Tags: c++, variadic

I need a function fulfilling the following functionality:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t SIZE_L, std::size_t ...SIZE_R>
std::array<T, SIZE_L> concat(const std::array<T, SIZE_R...>&);
```

This is supposed to concatenate all passed arrays on the RHS into a single array. The sum of SIZE_R should be identical to SIZE_L -- and if possible one should not need to specify SIZE_L by hand.

The element type of this array will be always double.

Comment: can you use `auto` as return type?

Comment: `SIZE_L` -> `(... + SIZE_R)` (C++17)

Comment: Is `T` default constructible?

Comment: But you can do: `std::array<NonDefaultConstructible, 2> arr{{ NonDefaultConstructible(42), NonDefaultConstructible(51) }};`...

Comment: @ Jarod42 -- sorry -- it is default constructible!

Answer (score 4):

With default constructible `T`, you might do (C++17):

```
template<typename T, std::size_t ...Ns>
std::array<T, (... + Ns)> concat(const std::array<T, Ns>&... arrs)
{
    std::array<T, (... + Ns)> res;
    std::size_t offset = 0;
    
    ((std::copy(arrs.begin(), arrs.end(), res.begin() + offset),
      offset += arrs.size()),
     ...);
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19c00226d1647714)

Comment: @FrankPuck: Concatenation would require some copies... (My version does extra default construction though).

Comment: range-v3 has a concat view, but then, result would no longer be contiguous.

Answer (score 3):

If needed, here's a version that can deal with a type which can't be default-constructed ([try it online](https://tio.run/##lVVNb9pAEL37V4yoFNkKkJCkimSML/2QcuGSSj20lbVZhnTV9Ue844jU4q@XjhezNiRKiIWQeX5vZvxmZpFFMZJaZPebzQeVSV0tECJRluIp9jqAngpMqBSKTB@uSGlF@8yq0Bh7XiZSNIWQCDZYIvNMCkp@oy6whNrzCNNCC2KJoUUYGvWXM8DNYjWEJlujh1sGb/Ghh3zJxJ3G2WOuFrFnqKwkgcoWSqLxag/4MiRISeB8hnBVlNAPb6tLWIArmMH59G0FakydgKubeuvpq8X3ga@qNDTfx8bj8dwc1h51UpsrMfhQYSYx2oWYGxbGw7Zg5qF1IlHLhCKf5RDP2nxBHL/bC0ufwGm/oNFe@Qd1beuJw7AX5p12Wva783URDlvhhuTbC44/g25sExiy8xmxxmeUHZibIIbtuPqd3Qfl3PTaYd8U9mNxi0@acAyYoO2GqChvgMRaxuNkJaTQb1jMDrYGlkhVmUG9VbkK7pEi55Y5viuxC@O75IHDfhwdsjP@FyM2wJobsPaaz64LrzfhCMePNbM16YXDJQz7zXP2peJPa0j3br389XoIXRv4jc7OYOQur3fCqZx3F0XKhxwfnMbAPP@81PSJ8pJrK6o7rWTYDYZdgY7iq4zgUegKAwghTeyt3wL1@kDnyH7Qjlm9e/NWOgWutSjVI5sfthtF7qHdEAsIlfmBOxacu11hQ7iMQUzq@oLvhnDV9PYV8oTJF3V9/QbtimmXdT3ioB@HcM66RtCtg8zTO5Xhgreh7ZqYcCOYLi6DlrjMSx5dZp@cwIpN22m2Q3ywJTKvCKIIVuOdb/xjAINtlWvvGXHwMxs0Dd9s/smlFvdmM@LnM3l6OrnejL4LrfkbV/zn9x8)):

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

namespace array_concat_helper {

template <std::size_t Idx, typename SizeSeq, typename Enable=void>
struct indices
{
    static constexpr std::size_t tuple_index = 0;
    static constexpr std::size_t elem_index = Idx;
};

template <std::size_t Idx, std::size_t FirstN, std::size_t ...Ns>
struct indices<Idx, std::index_sequence<FirstN, Ns...>,
    std::enable_if_t<(Idx >= FirstN)>>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t tuple_index =
    1 + indices<Idx-FirstN, std::index_sequence<Ns...>>::tuple_index;
    static constexpr std::size_t elem_index =
    indices<Idx-FirstN, std::index_sequence<Ns...>>::elem_index;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t ...Ns, std::size_t ...Is>
std::array<T, (... + Ns)> concat(
    std::index_sequence<Is...>,
    const std::array<T, Ns>&... arrs)
{
    auto arr_tuple = std::tie(arrs...);
    return {{
        std::get<indices<Is, std::index_sequence<Ns...>>::tuple_index>
        (arr_tuple)
        [indices<Is, std::index_sequence<Ns...>>::elem_index]...
    }};
}

} // end namespace array_concat_helper

template<typename T, std::size_t ...Ns>
std::array<T, (... + Ns)> concat(const std::array<T, Ns>&... arrs)
{
    return array_concat_helper::concat(
        std::make_index_sequence<(... + Ns)>{}, arrs...);
}
```

Comment: Nice, can it make coffee and use movable sources too?

Comment: @Surt Not this version. But hmm, if we took the arrays as forwarding references and just used `typename C::value_type` and `std::tuple_size`, then we could mix and match lvalue and rvalue arrays with perfect forwarding...

Comment: Sad of the complexity induced by handling no default constructible types :-/